# Twitter tweet count - bug?

Tags: twitter, bugs

I think this is the best place to ask about this question. I recently created this account: http://twitter.com/sarcasticquotes

I have posted 3 tweets so far. (No 'private' tweets at all). It is showing 3 tweets but the Tweet count as 5. What can be the problem?

rgds

JP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're right. i see 3 but it says 5.

As you tweet more it will come back to normal this happened to me before.
[image]

Comment: thanks for confirming. I guess I need not worry much (as long as the offset is some constant +- a small number, I don't mind but if its too way off, it would be problem :)